# What is the proper way to create a thread-safe singleton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, singleton

We have a subclassed `NSNotificationQueue` that has some custom methods that enqueue a notification inside of a `dispatch_async` call in order to get out on the main thread.

We have a class method, `sharedQueue`, that returns your average Objective-C style singleton using `dispatch_once` and a static reference.

My question is if we call the `sharedQueue` method from a background thread is that singleton then tied to the background thread, and should that thread go away will the singleton also be removed? If so, should we ensure we create the singleton on the main thread?

This is our approach for if we need to ensure the singleton is created on the main thread:

```
+ (instancetype)sharedQueue
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    static BCOVNotificationQueue *notificationQueue;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            notificationQueue = [[BCOVNotificationQueue alloc] initWithNotificationCenter:NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter];
        });
    });
    return notificationQueue;
}
```

Comment: There is no need for your use of `dispatch_sync`.

Comment: jblaker - You said "in order to get out on the main thread” ... Do you mean “get the notification sent and received _on_ the main thread regardless of what thread it’s called from”? Or do you mean “get the notification sending and receiving _off_ the main thread”? While rmaddy and Paulw11 are correct that, insofar as singletons are concerned, the `dispatch_sync` to the main thread is not needed (it’s the whole _raison d’être_ of singletons), it actually does matter re `NSNotificationQueue`. But I can’t advise how to fix it until you tell us precisely what you’re trying to achieve.

Comment: @Rob yes, exactly, we want the notification to be received on the main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the proper way to create a thread-safe singleton?

The technique is simply:

```
+ (instancetype)sharedQueue {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    static BCONotificationQueue *sharedInstance;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[BCONotificationQueue alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

This is the standard, thread-safe instantiation of singletons.

But you say:

> We have a subclassed `NSNotificationQueue` ...

That explains your intuition about dispatching this to the main queue (because you’re dealing the `NSNotificationQueue` and that’s particular to which thread you invoked it). But you don’t want your singleton to be dispatching synchronously to the main queue. I’d suggest you decouple the instantiation of the singleton itself (using the above pattern) from the `NSNotificationQueue` that it needs.

Let’s assume, for a second, that your intention was to post to the main thread regardless of where you invoked `BCONotificationQueue`. Instead of subclassing `NSNotificationQueue`, you instead just make it an opaque `NSObject`, whose private implementation wraps the underlying `NSNotificationQueue` like so:

```
//  BCONotificationQueue.h

@import Foundation;

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface BCONotificationQueue: NSObject

@property (class, readonly) BCONotificationQueue *sharedQueue NS_SWIFT_NAME(shared);

- (void)enqueueNotification:(NSNotification *)notification postingStyle:(NSPostingStyle)postingStyle;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

and

```
//  BCONotificationQueue.m

#import "BCONotificationQueue.h"

@interface BCONotificationQueue ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNotificationQueue *queue;
@end

@implementation BCONotificationQueue

+ (BCONotificationQueue *)sharedQueue {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    static BCONotificationQueue *sharedInstance;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[BCONotificationQueue alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

- (instancetype)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.queue = [[NSNotificationQueue alloc] initWithNotificationCenter:NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter];
        });
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)enqueueNotification:(NSNotification *)notification postingStyle:(NSPostingStyle)postingStyle {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.queue enqueueNotification:notification postingStyle:postingStyle];
    });
}

@end
```

So, we’re going to instantiate our singleton like we always do with Objective-C, but behind the scenes we’re going to dispatch the instantiation of the wrapped `NSNotificationQueue` asynchronously (avoiding any deadlock risks) back to the main queue. And the wrapped `enqueueNotification` will do the same, ensuring that all of the notification queue operations happen on the main (serial) queue, while still enjoying singleton behavior of the `BCONotificationQueue` wrapper.

Comment: Thanks for writing this up! What exactly did you mean by "But you don’t want your singleton to be dispatching synchronously to the main queue"? The `enqueueNotification` overrides that I set up did exactly what you show in your example, I was doing them asynchronously not synchronously.

Comment: @jblaker - I was just talking about your `sharedQueue` implementation, which was doing `dispatch_sync` to the main queue. You don’t want to do that. Nor do you want to just remove it from `sharedQueue` and declare success, as suggested by others. You have to refactor it something like the above (e.g., not making it a subclass of `NSNotificationCenter`, but rather a wrapper of it) to make sure the instantiation of the `URLNotificationQueue` happens on the main thread, but also allow you to instantiate the singleton from whatever thread you want.

Comment: Understood, thanks! So is NSNotificationQueue a special case in that it does care about which thread it is created on while a standard NSObject does not? And in this case why is `dispatch_sync` the wrong thing to do in a singleton to ensure it is created on the main thread?

Comment: “So is NSNotificationQueue a special case in that it does care about which thread it is created” ... Yes. Most objects don’t care about which thread you create them on. If they’re not thread-safe, they might also care about access from multiple threads. But `NSNotificationQueue` has its own, very unique concerns. “why is `dispatch_sync` the wrong thing to do in a singleton” ... You can deadlock if you happened to instantiate this from the main thread. A `dispatch_sync` from a serial queue (such as main queue) to itself will deadlock.